# How to peek into collections.deque() next item in Python-3?

Tags: python-3.x, list, linked-list

[EDIT3]: Trying to shortly and simply explane why do I need to implement it this way made me re-thing the whole procedure and the new solution came to my mind, simpler and shorter (:D) It doesn't need the Nr_Heap class at all. So, in a way, case dismissed.

[EDIT1]: I've edited the question, maybe it will be more understandable now.

I'm implementing an algorithm that is based on some computational geometry procedures. The input is a polyline build of points:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, nr=0, x=0, y=0):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._nr = nr
        self._hierarchy = None
        self._is_left = 0       #0 - pt is on line
                                #1 - pt is on the left side of the line
                                #-1 - pt is on the right side of the line
        self._father = None
        self._mother = None
        self._nr_max = 0
        [.........]
```

The process starts from preparing Regions consisting of consecutive polyline points that are on the same (left or right) side of a line connecting Start and End polyline points (aka SE Line).

Preparing the Regions:

1. For each point of processed polyline count if its on the left or right side of SE Line,
2. Along the way prepare an intersection_list of points where a polyline's segment intersects SE Line (i.e. is_left property changes from left to right, or the other way around), marking start and end points of such segment,
3. Catch points on the left of SE Line and put them on an auxiliary Nr_Heap queue,
4. Divide points on this Nr_Heap into Regions (that is make a new region when points on the Nr_Heap are no longer consecutive),
5. Repeat 3. and 4. for the points on the right side of SE Line.

Nr_Heap is planned to be a `collections.deque()` data structure, like below. I'm omitting unrelevant functions in the code.

```
class Nr_Heap:
    """
    Deque of points, auxiliary to defying a Region_List
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._top = None
        self._tmp_bottom = None 

    @property
    def top(self):
        return self._top

    @top.setter
    def top(self, queue):
        self._top = queue    #queue: collections.deque()

    def pop(self):
    if self.top:
        try:
            self.top.popleft()
        except IndexError:
            #raise IndexError(f"The queue is empty, nothing to pop.")
            return None
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Nr_Heap queue not initiated, no queue to push point into.")
    return self.top
```

I need to implement a Nr_Heap clean function, that pops items, starting from the top, but only while they meet two criteria (see 4. above). Those are:

(1) next item to the current one exists and

(2) the absolute value of difference of those two (current and next) items ._nr (see Points class) values equals 1.

Those popped points are added to a Region structure. When no such items exists the popping stops, what means that after such cleaning there can still be more points in the Nr_Heap, waiting for new Region to be started.

I tried like this:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.top:
        p = self.top
        it = iter(self.top)
        try:
            n = next(it)
            n = next(it)
        except StopIteration as e:
            n = None
        while n and abs(p[0].nr - n.nr) == 1:
            p = self.pop()
            try:
                n = next(it)
            except StopIteration as e:
                n = None
    return self.top
```

I get a RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration (not a surprise, if I'm popping an item...), but I have no other idea how to do it.

So my question is: using collections.deque() - how to peek into next item and check its properties to have conditions for a "while" loop? Is it possible to peek into next item of a deque() at all? Or maybe into a list, or some other python's data structure that I could use instead? I could implement my own heap structure, of course, but I wanted to try with the Python's build ones.

[EDIT2]: I got enlighted (sort of ;)) and now it is doing what it is supposed to do (see the code below). But if someone could do it better or answer my question above I'd be most grateful.

```
def clean(self):
        while self.top:
            it = iter(self.top)
            try:
                n = next(it)
                n = next(it)
            except StopIteration as e:
                n = None
            if n and abs(self.top[0].nr - n.nr) == 1:
                self.pop()
            else:
                break
        return self.top
```

Comment: Can you show how this is supposed to work with a concrete example? What should happen with the items whose difference is not 1? Are they popped and discarded? Do they stay on the queue?

Comment: They just stay in the queue and the popping proces is terminated.  Later on other functions are checking the state of this queue, that is if the point they are processing is in this queue, and depending on the answer they do or not do some other stuff. It's pretty hard to explain shortly, 'cause the whole process is quite complicated.

Comment: It's a part of a bigger procedure. At the beginning there is a polyline of n points (class Point). Then the polyline is divided into parts (regions), that collect points that are situated on the same side, left or right of the line connecting start and end points of the polyline. Such regions are processed further on, points are being divided into starshaped polylines, convex hulls and other computational geometry structures. My Nr_Heap class is auxiliary to "catching" those regions. The heap is cleaned when the algorithm is looking for a starting point of a new region.

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide a concrete sequence of actions on this data structure, and the subsequent states it goes through? This question will only get the needed attention if you clarify *exactly* -- with examples -- how you want it to work.